# Apple ID password not being requested before installing an app from the App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

Why isn't my Apple ID password being requested before installing an app from Apple Store ? It always has before now.

I changed my password the other day and I have a feeling I must have done
something else to screw things up. I have an iPad 4 running 8.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings → General → Restrictions and set Require Password to Immediately to always be required to enter your password for purchases.

Comment: Thanks.I forgot to activate button requiring I.D. with free purchases also. Sharon B